# How to show a column as NULL if it doesn't exist in match?

Tags: postgresql, join, null, postgresql-10

I have a query as shown below.
In this query I am trying to get the result of orders which don't have messages (which I thought as null). But I was expecting that this query would produce a NULL in `message_id` if someone has an order and doesn't have a message. What should I do do reach my goal?

```
select *, a.message_id as x
from
  messages a
  FULL OUTER JOIN customers b ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN orders c ON c.customer_id = b.customer_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN delivery_templates d ON c.billing_template_id = d.delivery_template_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN products e ON a.product_id = e.product_id
  FULL OUTER JOIN order_items f ON f.order_id = c.order_id    
where
  a.seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)
  AND
  a.message_id ISNULL
```

Comment: I doubt the `seller_id` is in `messages`. In `orders` perhaps?

Comment: The prolem thoug is the too many `FULL` joins. Rewrite with `LEFT` joins and you'll solve it.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to get the result of orders which don't have messages.

In other words: *"where no message exists that is linked to the order at had"*. Rephrasing should help to understand the translation to the syntax in the `EXISTS` anti-semi-join:

```
SELECT *  -- or just the columns you need
FROM   orders o
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM messages
   WHERE  customer_id = o.customer_id
   );
```

Contrary to your question title there is no need to display any additional null values since these are, as requested, *the orders which don't have messages*.

To get orders which don't have messages o*f a certain kind* (`seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   orders o
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM messages
   WHERE  customer_id = o.customer_id
   AND    seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)    -- add that condition here
   );
```

All the other tables you joined seem to be irrelevant to the question, but might produce additional rows.

### Why?

> But I was expecting that this query would produce a NULL in `message_id` if someone has an order and doesn't have a message. What should I do do reach my goal?

The answer is almost buried in your statement: *... this query would produce a NULL in `message_id`*.

NULL values you get in columns of *missing rows* from an `OUTER JOIN` are filled in ***after the fact*** (produced by the query itself, not read from the table). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

> `FULL OUTER JOIN` returns all the joined rows, plus one row for each
>   unmatched left-hand row (extended with nulls on the right), plus one
>   row for each unmatched right-hand row (extended with nulls on the left).

The `WHERE` condition `a.message_id ISNULL` is true for two distinct cases:

1. There is no qualifying row in table `a`
2. There is a qualifying row in `a` and its column `message_id` holds a NULL value.

After your first predicate `a.seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)` in the `WHERE` clause enforces results with an ***existing*** row in `messages`, only rows with an actual NULL value in the column `message_id` would pass - which is impossible if `message_id` is defined `NOT NULL`, *and* contradicts your stated requirement that no such rows shall exist to begin with.

You could move the condition `a.seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)` from the `WHERE` clause to the join clause of an `OUTER JOIN`. But better use `NOT EXISTS` like demonstrated. Related:

- [Postgres Left Join with where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465260/postgres-left-join-with-where-condition/40477254#40477254)
- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about how you *display* or *project* `null` when the query returns it. Remember, `null` is a type that represents something. It has no fixed display/rendering. For that use `coalesce`,

```
SELECT coalesce(a.message_id, 'NULL') -- or whatever you want the result is `null`
```

instead of

```
SELECT a.message_id
```

null
For more information see the docs on [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL),

> The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not `null`. `Null` is returned only if all arguments are `null`. **It is often used to substitute a default value for null values when data is retrieved for display.**

Answer (score 1):

I think that your where conditions:

```
a.seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6)
```

and:

```
a.message_id ISNULL
```

are incompatible. The first one will only work when the JOIN returns a message record; the second one only when it doesn't. You should filter on `seller_id` in another table (`orders` perhaps?)

Comment: Why is it invalid, `CREATE TABLE messages (seller_id, message_id) AS VALUES (2,null),(3,null),(null,null); SELECT * FROM messages AS a WHERE a.seller_id in (2, 3, 1, 6) OR a.message_id ISNULL;`

Comment: @EvanCarroll it's not invalid, but it doesn't make sense (to me). I'd expect `message_id` to be the primary key of `messages`.

Comment: My previous comment was inexact. To be precise:  `a.message_id ISNULL` not only qualifies when the row doesn't exist, but also when it exists and the column is NULL (which is probably prevented by a `NOT NULL` constraint for a column named `message_id`).